# Node.js on Plesk: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, laravel, plesk

I have a real-time application with Laravel and Node.js on Plesk and installed Node.js Successfully.
[Node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU76R.png)

But I get this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lNKG.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you using window object in node.js?, because node.js doesn't have window object because it runs on serverside

Comment: Yes, after running `npm run dev` I haven't changed the file "public/js/app.js", and it works on localhost @Shailendra

Comment: I did some changes in app.js and get those errors: [1]- ReferenceError: window is not defined=> `var window = window || {};`, [2]- ReferenceError: document is not defined => `npm install jsdom --save` `var jsdom = require("jsdom"); var JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
GLOBAL.document = new JSDOM().window.document;`

Comment: [3]- wsHost: window.location.hostname, TypeError: Cannot read property 'hostname' of undefined => `npm install os --save` `var os = require("os"); var hostname = os.hostname();` and changed "window.location.hostname" to "hostname"

Comment: finally, I get this error ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined